# How to download all di.fm & sky.fm playlists at once?

Tags: music

I would like to download the radio station playlists available for free (LQ) by www.di.fm and www.sky.fm, because they offer no web/desktop app! But I don't always use my iPhone or Android tablet and their website navigation is way too cumbersome.

Is there a quick way to download **all** their stations *.pls?

I want to add them to my internet radio playlist (foobar). The only solution I found is [**this "hack"**](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Hack:di.fm-playlists), but I don't even understand what it says, i.e. where I place those scripts so that they do what they are intended to do.

I would highly appreciate your help in using the above scripts or find another way.
Maybe someone of you already made himself the work and can upload the playlist file here.
(It doesn't matter for me if sky.fm and di.fm are separated or in one file.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DI.fm allows you to download as `.pls`.

As for Sky.fm, you will have to manually download the files by entering this URL:
`listen.sky.fm/public3/STATIONNAME.pls`.

For example: `listen.sky.fm/public3/dreamscapes.pls`

Comment: My intention was to indeed download all playlists at once and without having to figure out the station name. So while this helps if I am willing to invest the time, it isn't what I am looking for. You can call me lazy.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. How exactly can i download all stations playlist from di.fm?

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the following text in a .pls file.
2. Edit with notepad to replace the text YOUR_KEY by your premium key or delete it if you are not premium.
3. Open the pls file in your favorite player :)

> [playlist]
>   NumberOfEntries=70
>   File1=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/trance.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title1=Digitally Imported - trance
>   Length1=-1
>   File2=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/vocaltrance.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title2=Digitally Imported - vocaltrance
>   Length2=-1
>   File3=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/ambient.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title3=Digitally Imported - ambient
>   Length3=-1
>   File4=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/bigroomhouse.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title4=Digitally Imported - bigroomhouse
>   Length4=-1
>   File5=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/breaks.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title5=Digitally Imported - breaks
>   Length5=-1
>   File6=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/chillhop.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title6=Digitally Imported - chillhop
>   Length6=-1
>   File7=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/chillout.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title7=Digitally Imported - chillout
>   Length7=-1
>   File8=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/chilloutdreams.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title8=Digitally Imported - chilloutdreams
>   Length8=-1
>   File9=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/chillstep.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title9=Digitally Imported - chillstep
>   Length9=-1
>   File10=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/chiptunes.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title10=Digitally Imported - chiptunes
>   Length10=-1
>   File11=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/classiceurodance.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title11=Digitally Imported - classiceurodance
>   Length11=-1
>   File12=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/classiceurodisco.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title12=Digitally Imported - classiceurodisco
>   Length12=-1
>   File13=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/classictrance.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title13=Digitally Imported - classictrance
>   Length13=-1
>   File14=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/classicvocaltrance.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title14=Digitally Imported - classicvocaltrance
>   Length14=-1
>   File15=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/clubdubstep.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title15=Digitally Imported - clubdubstep
>   Length15=-1
>   File16=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/club.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title16=Digitally Imported - club
>   Length16=-1
>   File17=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/cosmicdowntempo.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title17=Digitally Imported - cosmicdowntempo
>   Length17=-1
>   File18=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/djmixes.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title18=Digitally Imported - djmixes
>   Length18=-1
>   File19=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/darkdnb.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title19=Digitally Imported - darkdnb
>   Length19=-1
>   File20=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/deephouse.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title20=Digitally Imported - deephouse
>   Length20=-1
>   File21=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/deepnudisco.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title21=Digitally Imported - deepnudisco
>   Length21=-1
>   File22=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/deeptech.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title22=Digitally Imported - deeptech
>   Length22=-1
>   File23=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/discohouse.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title23=Digitally Imported - discohouse
>   Length23=-1
>   File24=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/downtempolounge.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title24=Digitally Imported - downtempolounge
>   Length24=-1
>   File25=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/drumandbass.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title25=Digitally Imported - drumandbass
>   Length25=-1
>   File26=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/dubstep.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title26=Digitally Imported - dubstep
>   Length26=-1
>   File27=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/eclectronica.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title27=Digitally Imported - eclectronica
>   Length27=-1
>   File28=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/electro.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title28=Digitally Imported - electro
>   Length28=-1
>   File29=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/electronicpioneers.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title29=Digitally Imported - electronicpioneers
>   Length29=-1
>   File30=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/electropop.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title30=Digitally Imported - electropop
>   Length30=-1
>   File31=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/epictrance.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title31=Digitally Imported - epictrance
>   Length31=-1
>   File32=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/eurodance.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title32=Digitally Imported - eurodance
>   Length32=-1
>   File33=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/funkyhouse.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title33=Digitally Imported - funkyhouse
>   Length33=-1
>   File34=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/futuresynthpop.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title34=Digitally Imported - futuresynthpop
>   Length34=-1
>   File35=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/gabber.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title35=Digitally Imported - gabber
>   Length35=-1
>   File36=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/glitchhop.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title36=Digitally Imported - glitchhop
>   Length36=-1
>   File37=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/goapsy.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title37=Digitally Imported - goapsy
>   Length37=-1
>   File38=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/handsup.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title38=Digitally Imported - handsup
>   Length38=-1
>   File39=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/harddance.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title39=Digitally Imported - harddance
>   Length39=-1
>   File40=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/hardtechno.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title40=Digitally Imported - hardtechno
>   Length40=-1
>   File41=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/hardcore.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title41=Digitally Imported - hardcore
>   Length41=-1
>   File42=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/hardstyle.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title42=Digitally Imported - hardstyle
>   Length42=-1
>   File43=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/house.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title43=Digitally Imported - house
>   Length43=-1
>   File44=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/latinhouse.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title44=Digitally Imported - latinhouse
>   Length44=-1
>   File45=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/liquiddnb.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title45=Digitally Imported - liquiddnb
>   Length45=-1
>   File46=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/liquiddubstep.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title46=Digitally Imported - liquiddubstep
>   Length46=-1
>   File47=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/lounge.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title47=Digitally Imported - lounge
>   Length47=-1
>   File48=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/mainstage.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title48=Digitally Imported - mainstage
>   Length48=-1
>   File49=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/minimal.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title49=Digitally Imported - minimal
>   Length49=-1
>   File50=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/moombahton.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title50=Digitally Imported - moombahton
>   Length50=-1
>   File51=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/oldschoolacid.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title51=Digitally Imported - oldschoolacid
>   Length51=-1
>   File52=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/classictechno.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title52=Digitally Imported - classictechno
>   Length52=-1
>   File53=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/progressive.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title53=Digitally Imported - progressive
>   Length53=-1
>   File54=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/progressivepsy.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title54=Digitally Imported - progressivepsy
>   Length54=-1
>   File55=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/psychill.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title55=Digitally Imported - psychill
>   Length55=-1
>   File56=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/psybient.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title56=Digitally Imported - psybient
>   Length56=-1
>   File57=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/russianclubhits.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title57=Digitally Imported - russianclubhits
>   Length57=-1
>   File58=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/sankeys.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title58=Digitally Imported - sankeys
>   Length58=-1
>   File59=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/scousehouse.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title59=Digitally Imported - scousehouse
>   Length59=-1
>   File60=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/soulfulhouse.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title60=Digitally Imported - soulfulhouse
>   Length60=-1
>   File61=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/spacemusic.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title61=Digitally Imported - spacemusic
>   Length61=-1
>   File62=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/techhouse.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title62=Digitally Imported - techhouse
>   Length62=-1
>   File63=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/techno.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title63=Digitally Imported - techno
>   Length63=-1
>   File64=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/trap.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title64=Digitally Imported - trap
>   Length64=-1
>   File65=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/tribalhouse.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title65=Digitally Imported - tribalhouse
>   Length65=-1
>   File66=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/ukgarage.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title66=Digitally Imported - ukgarage
>   Length66=-1
>   File67=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/umfradio.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title67=Digitally Imported - umfradio
>   Length67=-1
>   File68=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/undergroundtechno.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title68=Digitally Imported - undergroundtechno
>   Length68=-1
>   File69=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/vocalchillout.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title69=Digitally Imported - vocalchillout
>   Length69=-1
>   File70=http://listen.di.fm/premium_high/vocallounge.pls?YOUR_KEY
>   Title70=Digitally Imported - vocallounge
>   Length70=-1
>   version=2

Comment: Replaced dead link with the text directly

Answer (score 0):

My answer was initially the same as above, except I give the link to the di fm radio and not sky radio. The link would be something like this:

```
http://listen.di.fm/public3/insert_radio_name.pls
```

And you get radio name by clicking on any of the radios, it will be `http://www.di.fm/insert_radio_name` so this is the manual way to do it, and not all at once. And I'm not sure if it works for all stations.

It's not 5 clicks per station, it's just 1 hover and 1 click, but even if that sounds like a lot, you can right click on the Stations button and do an Inspect element and expand the submenu and the lists divs. There you can find the names of the stations and you're 1 copy paste away. Ooor, without expanding any further, copy the ul elements, paste them in a txt file and start doing find/replace to turn for instance:

```
<li data-ga-event="MainNav,channel-dropdown-click,@data-channel-key" data-channel-key="00sclubhits" data-channel-id="324"></li>
```

into

```
http://listen.di.fm/public3/00sclubhits.pls
```

How? First part is easy, notepad is enough, just replace this

```
<li data-ga-event="MainNav,channel-dropdown-click,@data-channel-key" data-channel-key="
```

with

```
http://listen.di.fm/public3/
```

And for the 2nd part you can google "notepad++ regex" and install notepad++ and come up with:

```
" data-channel-id="(\d)*"></li>
```

being replaced with

```
.pls
```

Then trim out the ul elements or replace them with empty string. In the end you will have em all in 1 file, like this: `http://pastebin.com/V0mPewCq`. If you want this done in 1 go, I suggest you pick up Java and do a crawler for the main page in case they change them and you don't want to go through this again.

I have yet to know how to get them all in a playlist or save them all at once from such a file. Either save each manually (you can use this `http://www.urlopener.com/home.html` if you don't want to paste each in a tab, but you still have to click Save As... ) or again automated with some script (I also found this but idk how trustworthy it is: `http://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/download-multiple-files-at-once-in-windows/`), or add each Location manually and save them all into 1 big playlist. It's all a 2 step because the .pls that they give you contains the true links.

Comment: Your answer is a bit hard to read. Could you rewrite it, so that it is clearer?

Comment: Edited and added a full current list for di in the end of the post.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses command line programs:
`curl` - cURL tool to transfer data from or to a server
`grep` - Grep a command-line utility that can search and filter text
*Linux users should find these either already installed or simply use their distro's package manager to install. Windows users can install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or a lighter weight toolset [Gnu on Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki).*

Solution:

The webpage http://listen.di.fm/public3/ is a json list. We only need to get the page using cURL search for the .pls links using grep.

Type this in a command terminal:

`curl -s "http://listen.di.fm/public3/" | grep -Po 'http://listen.*?pls'`

A subset of the output should be:

```
http://listen.di.fm/public3/trance.pls
http://listen.di.fm/public3/vocaltrance.pls
http://listen.di.fm/public3/chillout.pls
http://listen.di.fm/public3/house.pls
http://listen.di.fm/public3/harddance.pls
http://listen.di.fm/public3/eurodance.pls
http://listen.di.fm/public3/progressive.pls
http://listen.di.fm/public3/goapsy.pls
... etc.
```

Comment: I think it's better to add further explanation about the curl/grep commands. Since it's WebApps, you can't really assume command line knowledge. Would be best to tell that the user should run it from the command line and state that if the commands aren't available on the system - they can be downloaded. Also, there's no OS mentioned - so try to be general

Comment: @arieljannai - Noted. More detail added.

Answer (score -5):

You can download all the .pls files. After that you open this files in a text editor like notepad++. You´ll discover the true url for the station. Add these url in a streaming audio grabber.
You´ll download in real time as the music plays.
I recomend StremRipper for winamp (you really don´t need winamp to use it)
Open the program, press rightclick and paste the true url from the station like inside the PLS files (listen.sky.fm/public3/STATIONNAME.pls)

Dont forget to configure the output folder.

Comment: I asked about how to do that for all stations _at once_! I know myself that I can download individual stations and I already did that. I also don't need all the technical hoho you described: vlc and others can automatically merge them, so that's no problem too. So that's why I downvoted your answer, you didn't even read my question. The problem is the di.fm/sky.fm websites themselves, that force me to do 5-x clicks to download the respective station, multiply this by 30 and I am busy half an evening just clicking around on di.fm.